# AIR Application not updating using ApplicationUpdaterUI

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, auto-update, flex4.6

I am working in Flex 4.6 AIR application. There is a button when i click on it, It downloads the new version of the application from the server and installed it automatically when AdobeAIRInstaller version 3.8 already installed in my system (both windows and MAC).

When i update the Adobe AIR version from 3.8 to 3.9. the installation process working fine in windows pc but in mac when i click to update, it downloads the application from the server but not installed it automatically.

My Code of XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/2.5">
    <versionNumber>1.2.9</versionNumber>
    <url>File Path URL</url>
    <description><![CDATA[
1. Test swf file secure.
  ]]></description>
</update>
```

And the code for update is following

```
protected function btnUpdate_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener( Event.EXITING, 
                    function(e:Event):void 
                    {
                        var opened:Array = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows;
                        for (var i:int = 0; i < opened.length; i ++) 
                        {
                            opened[i].close();
                        }
                    }); 

                appUpdater = new ApplicationUpdaterUI();
                // Configuration stuff - see update framework docs for more details
                appUpdater.updateURL = modellocator.appUpdateURL; // Server-side XML file describing update
                appUpdater.isCheckForUpdateVisible = false; // We won't ask permission to check for an update
                appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, onUpdate); // Once initialized, run onUpdate
                appUpdater.addEventListener(StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR, onStatusUpdateError);
                appUpdater.addEventListener(StatusUpdateEvent.UPDATE_STATUS, onStatusUpdate);
                appUpdater.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError); // If something goes wrong, run onError
                appUpdater.initialize(); // Initialize the update framework             
            }

            private function onStatusUpdate(event:StatusUpdateEvent):void
            {
                trace("Update Status");
            }

            private function onUpdate(event:UpdateEvent):void 
            {
                appUpdater.checkNow(); // Go check for an update now
            }

            private function onStatusUpdateError(evt:StatusUpdateErrorEvent):void 
            {
                showAlertMessage(resourceManager.getString('languages','msgInternetNotConnected'), "", "", 286, 142);
                modellocator.timerClosePop = new Timer(5000);
                modellocator.timerClosePop.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, removeErrorMessage);
                modellocator.timerClosePop.start();
            }

            private function removeErrorMessage(event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(messageAlertPopup);
                modellocator.timerClosePop.stop();
            }

            private function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void 
            {
                trace(event.toString());
            }
```

Please anyone tell me why this is behaving just like that.

Comment: I think this might be a known issue to 3.9. See: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3648402

Answer (score 0):

Just proceeding with an update to the latest version of Adobe Air (>= 3.9.0.1210) is fixing the ApplicationUpdaterUI() problem in Mac OS X.